# Call Method As Property Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, methods, properties

What's the difference between these two?

```
[SomeClass.classMethod instanceMethod];
[[SomeClass classMethod] instanceMethod];
```

`classMethod` of `SomeClass` returns a singleton object, on which the `instanceMethod` is called. Both methods work, and Xcode doesn't complain during execution or in code. However, typing `SomeClass.classMethod` doesn't show any matches in the dropdown whereas `[SomeClass classMethod]` does. Is this just a missing feature or a deliberate attempt to prevent this kind of practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dot syntax (`SomeClass.classMethod`) is just a syntax sugar for sending message (`[SomeClass classMethod]`). They do equal things.

You don't see completions for properties (dot syntax) probably because the object you are trying to access property of, is not properly casted to the type having that property:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.myproperty // <-- No completion
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate myproperty] // <-- Completion
```

This happens because the `delegate` is an `id` and thus has no properties (it's object of a generic type), so autocompletion can't suggest anything. The latter one is sending message to the object of generic type, so the compiler can suggest you lots of messages to send (no matter whether that object supports them).

Comment: Thanks, that's probably why. Must remember not to depend on the autocomplete too often, at times I have to build for it to kick in, or type in a different part of the screen.